# How to initialize classes in constructor using Moose

Tags: moose

The way I'm doing it is:

```
package 'My::FH';
use Moose;

has 'csv' => (
 is => 'ro',
 isa => 'Text::CSV',
);

sub store_data {
    my $self = shift;
    ... read lines...
    $self->csv->parse($line);
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

but when calling `$self->csv->parse` in the subroutine I get the following error:

```
cant call method 'parse' on an undefined value
```

It's not entirely clear to me how OOP works with Moose; is `has` a replacement for `use`? If so, I'm not sure why the module specified isn't instantiated (or maybe it is??).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has` is not a replacement for `use`; it is completely different. `has` declares an attribute in your class.

Your declaration:

```
has 'csv' => (
  is => 'ro',
  isa => 'Text::CSV',
);
```

simply declares an attribute called `csv` that is readonly `ro` and is of the type `Text::CSV`. But the type declaration does not import the module for you. You will need to `use Text::CSV` separately.

An object instance of My::FH will also need a reference to an instance of Text::CSV. Somewhere in your code you need to instantiate Text::CSV and assign it to your `csv` attribute. Moose does not initialise the attribute automatically for you (unless you include some extra options in your attribute declaration). You could do it using the `default` or `builder` (with `lazy`) options:

```
has csv => (
  is      => 'ro',
  isa     => 'Text::CSV',
  default => sub { Text::CSV->new( { your => 'options' } ) },
);
```

Alternatively, you could pass it to the constructor (though I'm guessing this is not what you're looking for):

```
my $fh = My::FH->new( csv => Text::CSV->new );
```

Have a read of this section of the Moose manual: https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::Attributes.